# How to set the range of a list?

Tags: haskell

I have to write a code that that returns all numbers in the input list within the range given by the first two arguments.

I tried to set the head of the list as the lowest input.

```
inRange :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
inRange lo hi xs = (x == lo : xs == hi)
```

I expect having a result such as 
`inRange 5 10 [1..15]  ==  [5,6,7,8,9,10]`, but since I cannot write the code the modular is not loading.

Comment: What do you mean with "since I can not write the code".

Comment: Can you explain why you think the above fragment, will generate the desired output?

Comment: Do you expect that `xs` is ordered? What about the infinite list?

Answer (score 4):

We can [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) the list, such that it only retains values `x` for which `lo <= x && x <= hi` holds:

```
inRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
inRange lo hi = filter (\x -> lo <= x && x <= hi)
```

We can optimize this for the case where `lo > hi`, since then, no element can satisfy the condition, and hence we can return an empty list.

```
inRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
inRange lo hi
    | lo > hi = []
    | otherwise = filter (\x -> lo <= x && x <= hi)
```

Comment: It's can be a bit optimized checking that `lo` is less than `hi` and return an empty list if not.

Answer (score 1):

with list comprehensions

```
> inRange lo hi xs = [ x | x <- xs, x>=lo && x<=hi ]
> inRange 5 10 [1..15]
[5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

With pattern matching you can do this like:

```
inRange :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
inRange _ _ [] = []
inRange lo hi (x:xs)
  | lo > hi             = []
  | lo <= x && x <= hi  = x : (inRange lo hi xs)
  | x > hi              = []
  | otherwise           = inRange lo hi xs
```